# Is there a way to show a gif in a generated mail?

Tags: html, css, email, gif

I am trying to create an auto-generated mail and I want to set the background to a gif. but I am not seeing any result. I have tried many things but they dont seem to work i thank you in advance. I have already background table and body Background But the Gif isn't showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this too. But most email providers are blocking images for security reasons, along with css animations and backgrounds. Also javascript is blocked by pretty much all of the email providers. So i do not think it is possible.

Comment: thx for the quick answer. so there is really no other way to show animations in a mail format

Comment: i think the only animation thats supportet bij most providers is an hover.

Comment: @JDEV An animation could be made through a css :hover selector and a transition, that will work in most cases. But i assume u meant inserting a gif, that is in most cases blocked. You could just only send a link though, referencing to an html page with the desired gif as a background.

Comment: @klaasjanloosman great idea, thx for the quick reply's and the feedback